# 'PFQuery' does not have a member named 'objectForKey'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6

So I am using swift to make an iOS app, I am also using Parse with it. To learn Parse I have been following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q6qcrO8uNzU&list=WL&index=1&spfreload=10
but when I to get to retrieving the text from the Parse Core Data and setting it equal to the Text View in my cell I get this Error: 'PFQuery' does not have a member named 'objectForKey'
Code Below:

```
cell.messageTextView.text = message.objectForKey("Content") as String
```

How would this be fixed? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: What is the type of `message`?

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that your variable 'message' is the wrong type. The method `objectForKey()` exists on the `PFObject` (i.e. https://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFObject.html) but not `PFQuery` (https://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFQuery.html).

Comment: @Glen_T Ok I fixed that but now I'm getting: 'MessageTableViewCell' does not have a member named 'messageTextView'

Comment: Sorry this is a different problem, you haven't provided enough information to explain this issue, but probably would make sense to be a different question?